# Merging 2 vectors and removing all repetitions

Tags: r

Say there is a vector:

```
v1 <- c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo", "da", "sm", "ez-de") 
v2 <- c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo-da", "sm", "ez", "de")
```

How do you merge the two vectors above so that we get the following?

```
c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo-da", "sm", "ez-de")
```

Note that the two vectors above have the same length..

Comment: Can you show any other patterns?

Comment: The two vectors are always same length. You always keep the elements with the dash and only use the repeated elements once. Any elements without the dash are always repeated elements in the two vectors

Comment: c("lol", "it","is", "now", " jab-time"). and c("lol", "it-is", " now", "jab", " time").  merge into c("lol", "it-is", " now", "jab-time").   The last element in one of the vector js always a dashed element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a stepwise approach to the solution; steps can be reduced once understood

```
# case 1. 
a=c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo", "da", "sm", "ez-de") 
b=c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo-da", "sm", "ez", "de")
# [1] "ab"      "bc"      "cd"      "ef"      "sm"      "yolo-da" "ez-de" 

# case 2.
a = c("lol", "it","is", "now", " jab-time")
b = c("lol", "it-is", " now", "jab", " time")
# [1] "lol"      "now"      "it-is"    "jab-time"

a = trimws(a)  # since observed that case 2 . "now" had whitespaces
b = trimws(b)  # these 2 steps are unnecessary, just check if that was a typo

c = intersect(a, b)  # extract the common values from both vectors
a = a[!(a %in% c)]   # keep only those which are not there in c
b = b[!(b %in% c)]   # keep only those which are not there in c

d = grep("-", c(a, b), value = TRUE)  # this returns only those having "-" in it

ans <- c(c , d)
```

Answer (score 3):

If order of the values is not a concern, we may try this:

```
v <- union(v1, v2)
Filter(function(x) length(grep(x, v))==1, v)
# [1] "ab"      "bc"      "cd"      "ef"      "sm"      "ez-de"   "yolo-da"
```

Answer (score 2):

My aproach:

```
library(dplyr)

a=c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo", "da", "sm", "ez-de") 
b=c("ab", "bc", "cd", "ef", "yolo-da", "sm", "ez", "de")

ab <- c(a,b)
ab_unique <- unique(ab)

ab
ab_unique
```

Comment: I prefer this approach, although note unique() is base R not Dplyr